# Test with mock for a function in python

Tags: python, unit-testing, exception, mocking

For the test coverage I want to test also the exception block of this function that is in the file 'signalC':

```
 class SignalC:
    def readSignal(self, a):
    try:
        with open(os.path.join(self.newSubFolder, "my file" + '.csv'), 'a') as csvfile:
            writer = csv.writer(csvfile, delimiter=',', quotechar='|',
                                quoting=csv.QUOTE_MINIMAL, lineterminator='\n')
            print 'Reading'
            z = random.uniform(-0.1, 0.1)
            readValue = z + setP[element]

            writer.writerow([self.element + '-' + str(element+1),)
    except IOError as message:
        logging.error('Error in writing the csv file ' + str(message))
        print(message.strerror)
        raise IOError
```

So far I tried with this approach, but still cant go inside the exception block:

```
def testReadSignal(self):
    sc = signalC.SignalC()
    a = [1, 1, 1]
    with mock.patch("signalC.SignalC.readSignal", side_effect=IOError("IOError")):
        self.assertRaises(IOError, sc.readSignal, a)
```

Or I should instead raise the exception with a wrong input? Can anyone give any example? Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It appears you want to create an instance of `SignalC` and then call that `readSignal` method. So you shouldn't patch that method itself (`"signalC.SignalC.readSignal"`) because that means it'll be mocked and you won't be calling the real implementation of that method.

You could raise the `IOError` when calling `open` for example:

```
def testReadSignal(self):
    sc = signalC.SignalC()
    a = [1, 1, 1]
    with mock.patch("signalC.open", side_effect=IOError("IOError")):
        self.assertRaises(IOError, sc.readSignal, a)
```

Comment: Thanks  lot! I dont know why I didnt think about open to raise the error